# Is the field wavefunction sum or product of the wavefunctions of individual modes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction

I understand that each mode has its own wavefunction. I would like to know, how do I calculate the wavefunction of a quantum field? Should I multiply or sum the wavefunctions of the individual modes?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you *mean* by "wavefunction of a quantum field". Quantum fields involve an infinity of oscillator operators acting on the Fock vacuum. If you (over-)simplified the field as a 2 mode system, with subscripts 1 and 2,
$$\phi = c_1 a^\dagger _1 +  c_1^* a  _1  + c_2 a^\dagger _2 +  c_2^* a  _2, $$
then the implied tensor-product structures would  generate product Fock states
$$
a_1^{\dagger k} a_2^{\dagger j} |0,0\rangle,
$$
where I denote the empty vacuum with the vanishing occupation number of each mode, so a symmetrize tensor product of 1-2-states.
If you absolutely *had* to consider space wave functions, you'd have a conventional product of wavefunctions,
$$
\langle x_1| \langle x_2|n_1,n_2\rangle = \psi (x_1) \psi(x_2),
$$
(real) Hermite functions whose arguments $x_1$ and $x_2$ have *absolutely nothing* to do with our spacetime, and merely keep track of the decoupled mode indices in notional  spaces.

I fear you are actually asking a messier question, namely ***eigenfunctions*** of such field operators, as, e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438049/eigenstates-in-qft-and-amplitude-of-a-field-operator) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312006/schr%C3%B6dinger-wavefunctional-quantum-field-eigenstates)  and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/456985/what-are-the-orthogonal-eigenstates-of-the-field-operator) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292899/creating-a-qm-state-of-definite-position-in-fock-space) ... questions. The site is full of them. Again, the most direct answers revolve around states, not eigenfunctions.

However, having solved that problem, you may mimic a [functional](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484631/calculating-wavefunctionals-for-general-qft-states-or-one-particle-states) Schroedinger equation.

All of these structures involve products of wavefunctions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should multiply the wavefunctions of individual oscillators. If you have several independent systems, the wavefunction of the composite system is a product of the wavefunctions of individual systems (like a probability distribution of a system consisting of several independent variables is a product of individual probability distributions).